# How do I open the machine.config from .NET v2.0.50727

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, machine.config

The application I want to read settings from writes to the  section of the machine.config in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG.

But when I use the following code:

```
Configuration myMC = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMachineConfiguration();
Console.WriteLine(myMC.FilePath.ToString());
```

The path returned is always the .NET 4 machine.config:

```
c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

Edit: my app uses MEF, so it requires .NET 4, writing the app from .NET 2 is not an option.

Comment: Is your project properties set to use the 2.0 framework or the 4.0 framework?  Or are you attempting to open 2.0 MachineConfig from a 4.0 codebase?

Comment: I am using the 4.0 framework, so yes, I need to open the 2.0 machine.config from 4.0 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open it as an xml or text file, see: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548

You could create a service that runs in .net 2.0, and call that service from your .net 4.0 app.

But why do you need to do this?

Comment: The machine.config contains user defined architecture information (about another product) that I need.

Comment: Then the simplest way is just to open the file with an xml reader

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that there is a way to specify which machine.config to open with a ConfigurationManager:

```
ConfigurationFileMap myCFM = new ConfigurationFileMap(fPath);
Configuration myMC = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(myCFM);
Console.WriteLine(myMC.FilePath.ToString());
```

where fPath was the Path to the one I wanted. I got that by digging through the registry.